# How to search with a regex pattern with a regex string in property file through Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, list, file, properties

I do have a property file with Key = Value Pair ,

*Property file name = "johhny_johhny_yes_papa.properties"*

```
prop.org.size = 5
user.id.name = johnny
name.account.id = jimmy
cassandra.user.name = yes
kakfa.user.name = org
```

I do have a list of string like below -

```
List_papa = ['org','johnny','jimmy','yes','papa']
```

My Goal is to search for the strings present in the list above is available inside the property file after =(equal) symbol and print that line.

**My code -**

```
ENV_PROP = "johhny_johhny_yes_papa.properties"
List_papa = ['org','johnny','jimmy','yes','papa']
with open(ENV_PROP) as f:
    file_content = f.read()
    contents = file_content.split('\n')
for line in contents:
    for user in List_papa:
        if (re.findall("\\b"+user+"\\b",line)):
            print(line)
```

**My Output -**

```
prop.org.size = 5
user.id.name = johnny
name.account.id = jimmy
cassandra.user.name = yes
kakfa.user.name = org
```

It is actually printing everything , because my if condition is True in all the lines .

**My expected output is  -**

```
user.id.name = johnny
name.account.id = jimmy
cassandra.user.name = yes
kakfa.user.name = org
```

I want to search the list elements in after =(equalto) symbol of the property file.

I got this below regex

```
(?<==).+$
```

The above mentioned Regex will get me the strings after "="(equalto) symbol .

So i tried applying this regex with my above code  -

**updated code-**

```
ENV_PROP = "johhny_johhny_yes_papa.properties"
List_papa = ['org','johnny','jimmy','yes','papa']
with open(ENV_PROP) as f:
    file_content = f.read()
    contents = file_content.split('\n')
for line in contents:
    regex_line = re.findall(r"(?<==).+$",line)
    for user in List_papa:
        if (re.findall("\\b"+user+"\\b",regex_line)):
            print(line)
```

I am getting this below error.

**`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`**

What is wrong with my above code , Kindly help me with the right code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.endswith` You can pass multiple params to `str.endswith` as a tuple

**Ex:**

```
List_papa = ('org','johnny','jimmy','yes','papa')   #Note! List_papa is a tuple
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith(List_papa):
            print(line)
```

**Output:**

```
user.id.name = johnny
name.account.id = jimmy
cassandra.user.name = yes
kakfa.user.name = org
```